# How to generate a copy with two arrays?

Tags: json, azure-rm-template

I need create a concatenated name in a copy loop that has two different arrays

Example:

```
Array1 [machine1, machine2]
Array2 [100, 100, 100]
```

I want my copy loop to be able to create this:

```
machine1_Disk0 - This will be 100GB
machine1_Disk1 - This will be 100GB
machine1_Disk3 - This will be 100GB

machine2_Disk1 - This will be 100GB
machine2_Disk2 - This will be 100GB
machine2_Disk3 - This will be 100GB
```

I already tried this ones:

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('Array1'), '_Disk_' , copyIndex('Array2'))]",
```

did not work cos Array1 is an array and not a positon inside the array. Then I tried this:

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('Array1')[copyIndex()], '_Disk_' , copyIndex('Array2'))]",
```

This told me that '' resource didnot exist.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: you should specify the program language you are using

Answer (score 0):

Java Script:

```
['m1', 'm2'].forEach((e) => { 
  [100, 150, 200].forEach((n, i) => { 
     console.log(e + '_Disk' + i +' This will be '+ n + 'GB') 
  }) 
})
```